# 404 page not found in YAMS

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, modx

I would like some help here. I am using MODx with YAMS module which is for multilingual. I follow the installation and setup document from YAMS but I still get 404 page not found.

I would like to get:

> localhost/sub/en/index.php?id=1
>
> localhost/sub/fr/index.php?id=1
>
> localhost/sub/th/index.php?id=1

the original link is

> localhost/sub/index.php?id=1

here is rewrite rule in htaccess file. I got the rewrite rule from YAMS in "Server Config" tab.

```
# Friendly URLs
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets) - [L]

# Redirect from mydomain.com/rootname to mydomain.com/rootname/
RewriteRule ^en$ en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr$ fr/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^th$ th/ [R=301,L]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^th/(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I am trying to search all the solutions everywhere. still no luck. please suggest or point me what i do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `/sub/en` get redirected to `/sub/en/`? Check if htaccess is enabled by putting some random text into the htaccess file, and see if you get a 500 error-page?

Comment: usually YAMS adds /en/ directly after the domain name, so you'd get www.example.com/en/sub/

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting links like localhost/en/index.php?id=1 in the frontend You have to fill the "MODx Subdirectory" field with "sub". You will find it in Modules->Yams->Other Params

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is .htaccess file. I copys all .htaccess from YAMS and replaces the whole original .htaccess file. To solve my problem, I copy only friendly URL part and replace only this part in original .htaccess file.

here what I copy from YAMS and replace in my .htaccess file:

```
# Redirect from mydomain.com/rootname to mydomain.com/rootname/
RewriteRule ^en$ en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr$ fr/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^th$ th/ [R=301,L]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^th/(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Many thanks for suggestions.